# Select only n rows in an SQL for an element

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-values

I have a table with a lot of columns for each table2_id I would like to have only the 5 rows with the largest id

```
id | table_2_id | name
----------------------
1  | 1          |A
2  | 1          |B
3  | 1          |C
4  | 1          |D
5  | 1          |E
6  | 1          |F 
7  | 1          |F 
8  | 2          |G
9  | 3          |H 
10 | 3          |I
```

There are 7 elements that have 1 in table_2_id, and I would like to have 5

So I would like to have

```
id | table_2_id | name
----------------------
3  | 1          |C
4  | 1          |D
5  | 1          |E
6  | 1          |F 
7  | 1          |F 
8  | 2          |G
9  | 3          |H 
10 | 3          |I
```

Comment: What database are you using, MySql, SqlServer, ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by table_2_id order by id desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn<=5
```